# Why my I can not see my textinput when keyboard is open?

Tags: react-native, expo

title says

```
  const showFooter = () => {
    return (
      <View style={s.footerContainer}>
        <Pressable style={s.btnInput}>
          <FontAwesome name="photo" size={22} color="#eee" />
        </Pressable>

        <TextInput 
          onContentSizeChange={(e) => {
            const { height } = e.nativeEvent.contentSize;
            height > 45 && height < 100 && setHH(height);
            height === 43 && setHH(45);
          }}
          value={input} 
          onChangeText={e => handleChangeInput(e)} 
          multiline 
          placeholder='Gebe eine Textnachricht ein...'
          style={[s.footerInput, { height: hh }]} 
        />
        <Pressable style={s.btnInput}>
          <AntDesign name="camerao" size={26} color="#eee" />
        </Pressable>
        <Pressable style={[s.btnInput, s.marginMinus]}>
          <Fontisto name="paper-plane" size={22} style={s.paper} color="#eee" />
        </Pressable>
    </View>
    )
  };
  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior='padding' style={{flex: 1}}>

        <FlashList
          data={message}
          keyExtractor={i => i.id.toString()}
          renderItem={rowRenderer}
          extraData={message}
          estimatedItemSize={200}
          inverted
        />

    { /* INPUT */ }
      <View style={[s.footer]}>
        { showFooter() }
      </View>
  
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  )
};

  container: {
    flex: 1,
  //  backgroundColor: '#eee'
  },
  footer: {
    paddingHorizontal: 4,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    width: '100%',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  footerContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    paddingHorizontal: 5,
    width: widthScreen - 8,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 20,
    maxHeight: 100,
    borderColor: '#eee',
  },
  footerInput: { 
    width: widthScreen - 152,
    padding: 12,
    paddingLeft: 0,
    textAlignVertical: 'top',
  },
  btnInput: {
    height: 38,
    width: 38,
    backgroundColor: '#C71FF7',
    borderRadius: 200,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
```

[image]

[image]

I am very thankful for your help!!

.......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: In AndroidManifist.xml
try adding 
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Comment: @Pramod its only on iOS the problem

Comment: try this one 
react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view

Comment: @Pramoud I use flatlist I can not again use a scrollview inside flatlist

Answer (score 0):

Use KeyboardAvoidingView to adjust the view when the keyboard is opening.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboardavoidingview

Comment: I Already use it but not working

Comment: that thing barely works only sometimes